# Limit to number of weapon/armor enhancements?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, armor

If I wanted my party's spellcaster to enhance/enchant a weapon or piece of armor, is there a limit to the number enhancements it can have on it? I haven't read anywhere that there is a limit, but putting an unlimited number on them seems OP. I also remember the game Neverwinter Nights 2 limited you to 4, but it didn't follow the rules 100%.

Answer (score 10):

*Magic Item Compendium* updated and clarified weapons’ limits. These rules are in addition to those in the *Player’s Handbook*: for example, *Magic Item Compendium* does not repeat, but does not repeal, the rule that non-epic weapons and armor are limited to a +5 enhancement bonus.

But for the purposes of non-enhancement magic properties, we have the following rules:

#### Weapons

> A weapon with a special property must have at least a +1 enhancement bonus. You can’t simply have a *flaming longsword*—it would have to be at least a *+1 flaming longsword*. A single weapon **cannot have** a modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus property bonus equivalents) **higher than +10**, nor can it have a market price (not counting special materials or the price of the masterwork weapon itself) of **greater than 200,000 gp** (or 200,000 gp for each end of a double weapon). For weapons that exceed these limits, see *Epic Level Handbook*.

#### Armor

> To add a special property to a shield or suit of armor, the shield or armor must already have at least a +1 enhancement bonus. A single suit of armor or shield **cannot have** a modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus special ability bonus equivalents) **higher than +10**, nor can it have a market price (not counting special materials or the price of the masterwork armor or shield itself) of **greater than 200,000 gp**. For armor or shields that exceed these limits, see *Epic Level Handbook*.

#### General Limitation: You have to pay for it

Even self-crafted magical enhancements are expensive. You are unlikely to *actually want* to have more than +10-equivalent or 200,000 gp worth of properties much before epic levels anyway, simply because it is unwise to sink so much money into a single item. At the very highest levels (say 18th level and upward) you might have considered buying such an expensive item but it is a dubious choice even if it were allowed.

Comment: You might want to add a note that certain properties have a flat gp cost, not a bonus equivalence, and can therefore count only toward the gp limit.

Comment: @TuggyNE yes but a weapon/armor with a +10 bonus already costs the maximum 200,000GP leaving no room for these extras...unless you add some cheese like this http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86297/5891

Comment: @Ben-Jamin: That's not what I meant. In principle, a magic item could have nothing but +x000gp properties that bring it to 200,000gp and if so, it would still be limited accordingly. (Or, more realistically, a +8 or +9 equivalent could have a fair number of properties added but be limited likewise.)

Comment: @TuggyNE true..probably more to your 2nd part..I don't think there's enough of those +GP only costs to add up to 200 from +1 but u can definitely mix/match...I'd go ahead and cheese it..reduce a 200K weapon by 60K and add a few nice enchants

Answer (score 3):

The limit is based on the total enhancement bonus. Each enchantment has, listed as its price, a number, for example [Bane](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#bane) has a +1 for its price. A non epic weapon/armor can have only up to a total of +10, and at least +1 of it must be an actual enhancement bonus, and no more than +5 can be actual enhancement bonus.

So for example, a +1 Bane long sword would have the cost of a +2 weapon and has room on it for a total of +8 more on it.

An important note, some armor enchantments have an actual price and not a bonus, these do not count towards the limit.

Comment: What about epic items? What is their total enhancement bonus and maximum actual enhancement bonus?

Comment: An item is considered to be epic if either its enhancement bonus goes above +5 or its total bonuses goes above 10. With epic items there is no limit to how much can be on it. http://www.d20srd.org/indexes/epicMagicItems.htm

Comment: This answer is out of date with respect to *Magic Item Compendium*.

Comment: There are two limits, not just one, and armor (and weapon!) properties with a flat price instead of a bonus equivalent count toward the total value limit (200,000gp), even though they don't count toward the total enhancement limit (+10).